# Encoding column pandas using if condition

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, encoding

I am trying to encode a weekday_name column (str) in my dataframe to int. But I am getting the error **The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**

Could someone please help me understand why this error comes and what would be solution

Code I am trying with is:

```
def weekday_df(df):

    if (data_semi['Weekday_Name'] == 'Monday'):
        return 1
    elif (data_semi['Weekday_Name'] == 'Tuesday'):
        return 2
    elif (data_semi['Weekday_Name'] == 'Wednesday'):
        return 3
    elif (data_semi['Weekday_Name'] == 'Thursday'):
        return 4
    elif (data_semi['Weekday_Name'] == 'Friday'):
        return 5
    elif (data_semi['Weekday_Name'] == 'Saturday'):
        return 6
    elif (data_semi['Weekday_Name'] == 'Sunday'):
        return 7
    

data_semi['Weekday_Name'] = data_semi.apply(weekday_df, axis = 1)
```

Dataframe looke like below
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your solution change selecting values from variable `df` passed to function:

```
data_semi['Weekday_Name'] == 'Monday'
```

to:

```
df['Weekday_Name'] == 'Monday'
```

All together:

```
def weekday_df(df):

    if (df['Weekday_Name'] == 'Monday'):
        return 1
    elif (df['Weekday_Name'] == 'Tuesday'):
        return 2
    elif (df['Weekday_Name'] == 'Wednesday'):
        return 3
    elif (df['Weekday_Name'] == 'Thursday'):
        return 4
    elif (df['Weekday_Name'] == 'Friday'):
        return 5
    elif (df['Weekday_Name'] == 'Saturday'):
        return 6
    elif (df['Weekday_Name'] == 'Sunday'):
        return 7
```

Better/faster here is use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary:

```
d = {'Monday':1, 'Tuesday':2,'Wednesday':3,'Thursday':4,'Friday':5,'Saturday':6,'Sunday':7}

data_semi['Weekday_Name'] = data_semi['Weekday_Name'].map(d)
```